# Cassandra data modeling

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3, datastax

So I'm designing this data model for product price tracking.

A product can be followed by many users and an user can follow many products, so it's a many to many relation.
The products are under constant tracking, but a new price is inserted only if it has varied from the previous one.

The users have set an upper price limit for their followed products, so every time a price varies, the preferences are checked and the users will be notified if the price has dropped below their treshold.

So initially I thought of the following product model:

[image]

However "subscriberEmails" is a list collection that will handle up to 65536 elements. But being a big data solution, it's a boundary that we don't want to have. So we end up writing a separate table for that:

[image]

So now "usersByProduct" can have up to 2 billion columns, fair enough. And the user preferences are stored in a "Map" which is again limited but we think it's a good maximum number of products to follow by user.

Now the problem we're facing is the following:

Every time we want to update a product's price we would have to make a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO products("Id", date, price) VALUES (7dacedd2-c09b-46c5-8686-00c2a03c71dd, dateof(now()), 24.87);    // Example only
```

But INSERT operations don't admit other conditional clauses than (IF NOT EXISTS) and that isn't what we want. We need to update the price only if it's different from the previous one, so this forces us to make two queries (one for reading current value and another to update it if necessary).

PD. UPDATE operations do have IF conditions but it's not our case because we need an INSERT.

```
UPDATE products SET date = dateof(now()) WHERE "Id" = 7dacedd2-c09b-46c5-8686-00c2a03c71dd IF price != 20.3;    // example only
```

Comment: Just curious, but why do you need an `INSERT`?  Under the hood, `UPDATE` and `INSERT` are the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350630/when-are-rows-overwritten-in-cassandra/28351184#28351184

Comment: Because even though I made all the operations UPDATES i'd still have to provide a timestamp (which is in the primary key) to insert a certain product price. When inserting a new price at a given time, the new time doesn't exist in the database, and for that reason the update operation will always be treated as an insert (and will not check whether the last inserted price is the same).

Comment: Also, you don't want to do this: `dateof(now())`.  `DateOf` returns a timestamp, but `now` returns a timeuuid, which are of different precision.  This means that your data will have the appearance of a timestamp, but will actually store the timeuuid generated from `now()`, making it difficult for you to query by date range (if that's something you're planning to do): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237940/cassandra-cql-select-query-not-returning-records-which-have-timestamp-as-cluster/26239367#26239367

Comment: Good point there, querying by date range is a requisite, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to apply a normal model on a cassandra database. It may work but you'll end up with terrible performance and scalability.

The recommended approach to Cassandra data modeling is to first figure out your read queries against the database and structure your data so that these reads are cheap. You'll probably need to duplicate writes somewhat but it's OK because writes are pretty cheap in Cassandra.

For your specific use case, the key query seems to be able to get all users interested in a price change in a product, so you create a table for this, for example:

`create table productSubscriptions (
  productId uuid,
  priceLimit float,
  createdAt timestamp,
  email text,
  primary key (productId,priceLimit,createdAt)
);`

but since you also need to know all product subscriptions for a user, you all need a user-keyed table of the same data:

`create table userProductSubscriptions (
   email text,
   productId uuid,
   priceLimit float,
   primary key (email, productId)
)`

With these 2 tables, I guess you can see that all your main queries can be done with a single-row select and your insert/delete are straightforward but will require you to modify both tables in sync.

Obviously, you'll need to flesh out a bit more the schema for your complete need but this should give you an example on how to think about your cassandra schema.

**Conditional update issue**

For your conditional insert issue, the easiest answer is: do it with an UPDATE if you really need it (update and insert are nearly identical in CQL) but it's a very expensive operation so avoid it if you can.

For your use case, I would split your product table in three :

`create table products (
    category uuid,
    productId uuid,
    url text,
    price float,
    primary key (category, productId)
  )`


  `create table productPricingAudit (
    productId uuid,
    date timestamp,
    price float,
    primary key (productId, date)
  )`


  `create table priceScheduler (
    day text,
    checktime timestamp,
    productId uuid,
    url text,
    primary key (day, checktime)
  )`

**products** table can hold for full catalog, optionally split in categories (so that listing all products in a single category is a single-row select)

**productPricingAudit** would have an insert with the latest price retrieved whatever it is since this will let you debug any pricing issue you may have

**priceScheduler** holds all the check to be made for a given day, ordered by check time. Your scheduler simply has to make a column range query on single row whenever it runs.

With such a schema, you don't care about the conditional updates, you simply issue 3 inserts whenever you update a product price even it doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems ok and manageable and I'm pretty much sure I will incorporate it in the schema. However my main concern is still that I'm not able to conditionally insert a new price on an existing product... That is, checking whether the last existing price is different from the one to be inserted.

Comment: "productPricingAudit would have an insert with the latest price retrieved whatever it is since this will let you debug any pricing issue you may have"

Ok, thanks again but so many inserts is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want to store every price, just the possible changes. Why? Because I'll have 20+ workers that are continuosly checking the prices, and I'll probably end up with 1M+ insertions every day if I follow that model. That's why I need to store a new price only when it changes.

Comment: I would take the writes + a cleanup daily script but if you're concerned about storage usage simply add a lastPrice column in the priceScheduler table and do the compare with previous price in code. You have to read the priceScheduler data anyway and it seems unlikely in your application that 2 jobs may update the price of a given product at the same time

Comment: Use sparingly, but [lightweight transactions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html) might be what you're looking for on your "check before update" concern. Be sure you're aware of the cost before using them, though.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I will try to answer my own question: conditional inserts other than "IF NOT EXISTS" are not supported in Cassandra by the date, period.

The closest thing is a conditional update, but that doesn't work in our scenario. So there's one simple option left: application side logic. This means that you have to read the previous entry and perform the decision on your application. The obvious downside is that 2 queries are performed (one SELECT and one INSERT) which obviously adds latency.

However this suits our application because every time we perform a query to enqueue all items that should be checked, we can select the items urls and their current prices too. So the workers that check the latest price can then make the decision of inserting or not because they have the current price to compare with.

So... A query similar to this would be performed every X minutes:

```
SELECT id, url, price FROM products WHERE "nextCheckTime" < now();    

// example only, wouldn't even work if nextCheckTime is not part of the PK or index
```

This is a very costly operation to perform on a Cassandra cluster because it has to go through all rows that are stored randomly in different nodes by default. Another downside is that we need some advanced and specific statistics regarding products and users.

So we've decided that a relational database will serve us better than Cassandra in this particular case.

We sadly leave all of Cassandra's advantages (fast inserts, easy scaling, built in sharding...) and look towards a MySQL Cluster or master-slave implementation.